# OpenGL ES 2.0 - is there a way to read a pixel color from a grayscale texture?

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es

I load a texture with grayscale image using GL_LUMINANCE format.

when i use `float NP = texture2D(input1, textureCoordinate).r;` in the fragment shader the program fails.

is it possible to read the pixel grayscale value or am i limited to work with 4 channels only?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Likely you have an error elsewhere. Can you show your shaders, and the output of glGetShader/ProgramInfoLog when it fails?

Comment: When you say the program fails, do you mean it fails during compilation, or it runs but it returns a value that you do not expect in your float?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. Here is some GL code the loads a "height map" (grays levels stored as `float`'s).
The texture is stored in unit 0.

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureNames[0]);
...
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_LUMINANCE,
             heightMap.W, heightMap.H, 0,
             GL_LUMINANCE, GL_FLOAT, &heightMap.elev[0]);
```

Here is the pertinent code from my vertex shader. The uniform `HeightMap` is 0 (unit 0).

```
 float z = texture2D(HeightMap, TexCoord0).x * ElevScale + ElevShift;
```

Works like a charm.